# Is there any mechanism in PHP for caching code?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, caching, rack, passenger

Lately I have been reading about the Rack architecture in Passenger/Rails, and how it brings speed and lower memory usage for each request, by caching the code or classes when the server starts.

Is there anything similar for PHP? Something that keeps the code (not data) in memory, so the application don't need to read each file used every time.

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=php+code+cache Quite simple, isn't it?

Comment: @dagon It's in the title and in the body of the post. Try reading again

Comment: @Dagon Got up on the wrong side of the bed today? :)

Comment: @dagon Oh wow you are so smart and funny

Comment: Whoa. "Try reading again". Quite harsh attitude for someone asking such a silly question

Comment: @col-shrapnel How would you have answered to that? It's not like I forgot to make the question, is it. Just look at how other people answered, they have been very helpful. For instance, I had already looked into the APC thing before posting but from the examples I thought it was a regular cache library, not a library for caching code.

Comment: Guys, either find a duplicate or let this question be a question. It's legit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is called an **opcode cache**.  There are several:

- [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)
- [Xcache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/)
- [Even More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)

Comment: The easiest, most fool proof choice which is right in almost every situation is APC.

Comment: They downvote because they are too smart for this site. Yet they spend their lives here. Sad but true.

Answer (score 1):

The Alternative PHP Cache (APC) is a free and open opcode cache for PHP. Its goal is to provide a free, open, and robust framework for caching and optimizing PHP intermediate code.

this link will help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Answer (score 0):

APC - http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php is probably what you are looking for.  There are others as well - xcache & eacclerator, but my belief is that APC is the most widely used and I believe it is going to become part of PHP circa version 6.